# Save Videos OpenCV(python) - save several videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

can i save several videos, or each time i run the program the saved video is replaced?

because every time I run the program, the previously saved video is replaced by the new one

**for example. after write the video**

```py
 out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, fps, (int(width), int(height)))
```

it saves a file with the name "video", I wanted that the next time I run it save the next video as video1 etc ...

Comment: Can you be more specific, provide some context for this?

Comment: for example. after write the video this  ||||    out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, fps, (int(width), int(height))) "  |||||                                                                                             it saves a file with the name "video", I wanted that the next time I run it save the next video as video1 etc ...

Comment: That information should be in your post, not a comment.

Comment: yeah sry, im new here eheh, i'm gonna edit

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the class VideoWriter, you would have to create different instances of that class to write to files of different names. OR every time that your program runs, you change the filename argument for VideoWriter. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: have any example of the second option? change the name of the videowriter filenameargument?